# Download a file to a writestream but go directly to a readstream in node.js

Tags: node.js, google-api, stream, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to upload a file to youtube, using the the `googleapis/youtube` library. All examples online point to uploading a file from your local filesystem, the code is like this:

```
const data = await yt.videos.insert({
      resource: {
        // Video title and description
        snippet: {
          title: 'test',
          description: 'test desc',
        },
        // I don't want to spam my subscribers
        status: {
          privacyStatus: 'public',
        },
      },
      // This is for the callback function
      part: 'snippet,status',

      // Create the readable stream to upload the video
      media: {
        body: fs.createReadStream(
          path.resolve(
            '/Users/username/file.mp4',
          ),
        ),
      },
    });
```

The above code works, however, I want to download a file from a url and immediately pipe it into the call above, replacing the `fs.createReadStream` and bypassing the local filesystem entirely so I don't have to do cleanup afterwards or hit space limitations in a lambda (`/tmp` is 500MB max).

I read somewhere else you could use a `stream.PassThrough` stream but I'm not sure if there's a better way to do this.

TL;DR:
I want to go from

```
URL -> writestream -> filesystem -> readstream -> youtube
```

to

```
URL -> writestream -> youtube
```

Comment: It depends upon what you're using to download the file from a URL.  Most interfaces for that give you a readStream which can directly substitute instead of `fs.createReadStream()`.  Please show that code for more specific advice.  You don't have to use a passthrough at all.  Just pass the incoming stream directly.  This is the beauty of streams as they are interchangeable.

Comment: It's just a url from [snaptik](https://snaptik.app/en) which is an mp4 file, you can put any tiktok share url in and get a couple of download links. Here's [one](https://snaptik.app/file.php?token=1NzA4ODAyNjIzNDQ4NzA5ODYzMF92MDkwNDRnNDAwMDBjOWVyZG1iYzc3dTNxdWYyNjFwZ195ZWU%3D2&full_hd=1) -- I was planning to use axios to make a `GET` request and then somehow pipe it in

Comment: Let me try to use the `axios` read stream and plug that right into the body

Comment: yep, this works, had to look into the axios code a bit and it does create a readable stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With axios, you should be able to use the incoming stream directly:

```
const response = await axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: someURL,
  responseType: 'stream'
});
```

And, then use that stream directly:

```
  media: {
    body: response.data
  },
```